# How to return missing rows from LEFT JOIN in BigQuery

Tags: join, google-bigquery

How can we get BigQuery to return the rows in a LEFT JOIN which exist in TABLE A but are NULL in TABLE B?

```
-- find missing users. return rows which exist in A but not in B
select          a.user_id
from            database_a a  
left outer join database_b b on a.user_id = b.user_id 
where           b.user_id is null
```

Comment: What is the issue with the query you've posted? Seems like it should do the job, you just probably need to replace `select a.user_id` with `select a.*` (or an explicit column list instead of `a.*`) if you want entire rows instead of a single column, but in terms of finding the correct rows, it's the way to go AFAICT.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should work fine, but there's another approach which is slightly more specific and, at least in some RDBMS, slightly better perfoming:

```
SELECT
    user_id
FROM
    database_a.users AS A
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM database_b.users AS B WHERE A.user_id = B.user_id);
```

Note that the database does not actually retrieve any records from `B`, so this is one rare case where `SELECT *` is legitimate.  You could just make it `SELECT TRUE` or something as well.

Comment: This analysis is for MySQL, but the logic is largely the same in any SQL database: https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/